# Android layout orientation change in landscape mode

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-framelayout, landscape-portrait

I have a `FrameLayout` inside my fragment, and three other layouts inside my `FrameLayout`. I want one of the three layouts to change its view positions on a landscape, so I created two XML files for this layout and put them inside layout-port and layout-land accordingly, but the layout is still using the portrait layout in landscape mode. So what else do I need to do?

```
<FrameLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
      .
      .>
     <include
         layout="@layout/xxx"
         ...    />

      <include 
          layout="@layout/xxx2"
          ...    />

        ...
  </FrameLayout>
```

I want to change the layout of xxx on a landscape, and I created 2 XML for xxx.

Comment: http://code4reference.com/2012/09/orientation-specific-layout/

Answer (score 0):

The default folder for layout is `layout` no need to add port suffix to it, when you create a landscape version you should make sure that its in the folder layout-land and the device will automatically select this layout version at runtime. for more information on supporting different screen sizes look at this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)